# placement of unary operator when using pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to learn about pointers in C, and don't understand why the unary * operator was appended to the end of the word "node" in the following code snippet:

```
struct node* CopyList(struct node* head) {
    /* code here */
}
```

From my understanding of pointers, one can create a pointer with a statement like

```
int *pointerName;
```

and assign a "pointee" to it with a statement like

```
pointerName = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

and then dereference the pointer with a statement like

```
*pointerName = 4;
```

which will store the integer value 4 in the 4 bytes of memory (pointee location) which is "pointed to" by the pointerName pointer.

WITH THAT BEING SAID, what does it mean when the * is appended to the end of a word, as it is with

```
struct node*
```

???

Thanks in advance!

http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/103/

Comment: It's the return type of the function: It returns a pointer to `struct node`.

Comment: It returns a pointer to a `struct node`. It is not a dereference operator there.

Comment: There is no "unary operator" involved. Please find a good C textbook.

Comment: @KerrekSB The unary operator * is used when dereferencing a pointer. It may not be called such when used to initialize a pointer, but he is not so far off the mark.

Comment: @Hydronium: The `*` in the first line is not an operator. You couldn't be further off the mark if you were Samuel Clemens's jilted lover.

Comment: @KerrekSB Right. What is it called in that case?

Comment: @Hydronium: It's part of the type name.

Answer (score 3):

The location of the `*` ignores the whitespace between the base type and the variable name. That is:

```
int* foo; // foo is pointer-to-int
int *bar; // bar is also pointer-to-int
```

In both cases, the type of the variable is "pointer-to-int"; "pointer-to-int" is a valid type.

Armed with that information, you can see that `struct node*` is a *type*, that type being "pointer-to-node-structure". Finally, therefore, the whole line

```
struct node* CopyList(struct node* head)
```

means "`CopyList` is a function taking a pointer-to-`struct node` (called `head`) and returning a pointer-to-`struct node`"

Comment: I prefer to put the `*` as in the second example to indicate that the pointer is `bar`, so when you have `int *p_bar, bar;` you'll not be confused who's pointer and who's not.

Comment: I think about what is the object that I really care about. I'd use the first style if "foo" is the thing I care about (foo is a pointer to an int, or perhaps a pointer to a whole array of ints). I would use the second style if "*bar" is the thing I care about (*bar is an int).

Answer (score 1):

`struct node* CopyList`

To understand better you should read it from right to left. Which says `CopyList` is a function returning a pointer to node.

Answer (score 1):

`int *pointerName;` is the same as `int * pointerName;` or `int* pointerName;`. The data type is `int*` in all those cases. So `struct node*` is just a pointer to `struct node`.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use '*' either with type or with function name/variable name.**
But it is suggested to use it with **return type** while declaring methods, like shown below

```
    struct node* CopyList(struct node* head) {
     /* code here */
    }
```

when declaring pointers of a type use * with the  **variable name.**  like shown below,

```
    int *ptr;
```

Declaring in that way increases readability.

For example consider this case,

```
    int* a,b,c;
```

The above statement is appearing like declaring three pointer variables of base type integer, actually we know that it's equals to

```
    int *a;
    int b,c;
```

Keeping the * operator near the data type is causing the confusion here, So following the other way increases readability, but it is not wrong to use * in either way.

Answer (score 0):

`node*` means that the following function/variable/structure has type 'pointer to type node'.